# django compiling translation string in different machines

Tags: python, django, django-templates, translation

On my system i have changed mgstr in `django.po` and compiled it and i get the translation as expected.Now my question is should i run `manage.py compilemessages` even on the production machine or checkin the binary file(`django.mo`) so that when it is checked out on prod machine compilation step may be skipped. What is the standard way to go about this

Answer (score 0):

Typically, [.mo files are git-ignored](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Python.gitignore). This means it makes sense to re-compilemessages after you checkout the latest revision.

EDIT:

The procedure I use is the following: .po are part of git rep, .mo are git-ignored.

In development:

1. change the code (that potentially has translation strings),
2. run `python manage.py makemessages -l [language]`
3. edit the `.po`
4. (optional, to check possible mistakes: run `python manage.py compilemessages -l [language]` and runserver to test translations)
5. commit the changes of both the code and the .po
6. push to master

In production machine:

1. pull from origin
2. `python manage.py compilemessages -l [language]`

At this point, .mo is created on the production from the .po you pulled from the master.

One way to automate this is to use [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/), a python lib for writing automated scripts for deploying code (e.g. Django) on servers.

Comment: In production i dont see the translation. What might be the issue? Also how and when are the messages compiled on any new machine

Comment: @Rajeev, I added a more detailed description of the procedure.